# dollar format disappears when arranging in grid layout using pushViewport

Tags: r

I am trying to arrange graphs in a 2x2 grid layout with year on the X axis and Cost on the Y axis. When I format by individual graph my formatting, namely the dollar sign is there, but when I arrange it in the grid layout the dollar sign and commas disappear.

Code below:

```
rat<-qplot(tallc$Group.1,COSTS,data=tallc, geom=c("point","smooth"), 
method="lm",
           xlab= "YEAR",
           ylab= "COST",
           scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1999,2012)),
           main= "Total Costs from 1999 to 2012")      
rat1 <- rat+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,
           2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012))
rat1 + scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar)
```

the moment I use

```
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
print(a, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(b, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(c, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(rat1, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))
```

Dollar sign disappears.

Comment: Your data is not reproducible. We cannot see the `tallc` object. Please include data or fake data that looks like the real data. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of missing items (and the answer):

```
 tallc<-data.frame(COSTS=rnorm(9), Group=1999:2007)  # fake data
 require(ggplot2) # obvious
 require(scales) # not so obvious
 # first part of code
 ##### The missing step:
 rat1 <- rat1 + scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar)
 require(grid)
 # Second part: grid code
 # success with plotting dollar-scale in lower right corner
 # (despite errors from the missing a,b, and c objects.)
```

You never assigned the result of adding the `scale_y_continuous` with the "dollar sign" to `rat1`, so `rat1` remained in the same state it was in after adding only the x-scale.

Comment: This worked was not storing it as a separate object. DWin would you know how to standardize the y scales. I have two separate plots with two different x axis, one set of values are in calander years and the other are in fiscal years, I am trying to set the y breaks (units in dollars) to be the same for comparison of the two graphs. Attached is the code, but the y axises are different tried using breaks, lengths, and ylim option but it did not work. Code below.

Comment: code for plot 1                                                                   rat<-qplot(tallc$Group.1,COSTS,data=tallc, geom=c("point","smooth"), method="lm",
           xlab= "CYYEAR",
           ylab= "COST",
           main= "Total Reported Costs")      
rat1<-rat+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012))
rat1 + scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar)
ratf<-ratf + scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar)

Comment: code for plot 2  brain<-qplot(tallf$Group.1,COSTS,data=tallf, geom=c("point ","smooth"), method="lm",
         xlab= "FYEAR",
         ylab= "COST",
         main= "Total Reported Costs")      
brain1<-brain+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012))
brainf<-brain1 + scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar)
brainf

Comment: issue here is that the y axis is different for both plots and I want it to be the same

Comment: tallc-sample date                                              Group.1      COSTS  EVENTS
1     1999  166304548  652
2     2000  822939665  730
3     2001  472072396  566

Comment: Basically trying to set the breaks of the two y axis to be the same.

Comment: If you use `+ylim( range(c(tallf$COSTS, tallc$COSTS)))` to create new plot objects then the "breaks" should end being the same. You should NOT use the comments to a question to add new code for a new question. (I also think you should have asked a new question, since this really has nothing to do with your first question.)